# How to overcome the 'dependencyResolutionManagement() method not found' error when building a React Native native Android module with TomTom Maps?

Tags: react-native, tomtom, tomtom-android-sdk, native-android

React-native native android module. Facing several errors with this https://developer.tomtom.com/android/maps/documentation/overview/project-set-up . Trying to build a native android module for React native project. Can anyone tell me where to add this piece of code

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url = uri("https://repositories.tomtom.com/artifactory/maven")
        }
    }
}
```

in which file?build.gradle of app?build.gradle of project?settings.gradle?
wherever I add it is showing this following error...

> Could not find method dependencyResolutionManagement() for arguments
> [build_2lvry1fw81l4zm1hlike242ly$_run_closure2@35c8b4b1] on root
> project 'CheckFragNativeComp' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Can someone help resolving this error?
Tried the following

1. Created new RN project and tried to modify android folder
2. created seperate android project and tried to integrate existing app to RN

Answer (score 0):

You will need to place this code snippet in settings.gradle as instructed [here](https://developer.tomtom.com/android/maps/documentation/overview/project-setup).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.